# Upgrade to Jenkins 2.0 on Windows Server

Tags: jenkins, windows-server-2008-r2, jenkins-cli

We are currently running version 1.651.3 on our server and want to upgrade to version 2. From what I can tell online, I just need to run the .msi file and install into the current Jenkins directory and we're good. That didn't work, so I tried stopping the Jenkins service and installing again, but it is still running the old version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't realize that you could just download the [.war file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWBtC.png) instead of one of the deployment options. I was clicking **Windows** and getting the .msi instead of clicking **2.11 .war** and getting the .war file. I then dropped this into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` directory on my server and all was good in the world.